# How to add mask for padded sentences in LSTM layer in a binary classification problem?

Tags: python, keras, lstm, tf.keras, masking

I am trying to design a LSTM-CNN model using glove embeddings and some dialogue act information as text features, I have used padding at two levels: within a sentence to make all sentences of equal length, at document level, to make all documents of equal number of sentences. How I can add masking at both of the levels so that model learns that these sentences  are just padded sentences and not the actual sentences? Here is my code:

```
def create_model(conv_activation='sigmoid',kernel_size=4,filters=32,learning_rate=0.0001):
  EMBED_SIZE = 100
  EPOCHS=2
  max_conv=max_conversation_length
  max_words=length_long_sentence
  BATCH_SIZE=128
  total_features=input_size
  #learn_rate=0.0001#0.0001#0.01
  DA_tags_size=len(unique_tag_set)
  text_size=max_words
  DA_size=text_size+DA_tags_size
  ac_size=DA_size+max_acoustic_len
  
  all_input=Input(shape=(max_conv,total_features,)) 
  text_input=tf.slice(all_input, [0,0,0], [-1, -1,text_size])
  tags_input=tf.slice(all_input, [0,0,text_size], [-1, -1,DA_tags_size])
  acoustic_input=tf.slice(all_input,[0,0,DA_size],[-1,-1,-1])
  text_emb = Embedding(vocab_size, EMBED_SIZE, weights=[embedding_matrix],input_length=max_words, name='embedding',trainable=False,mask_zero=True)(text_input)
  hidden_vectors=TimeDistributed(Bidirectional(LSTM(units=128, return_sequences=False)) ,name='utterance_lstm')(text_emb )
  combined= Concatenate(axis=-1)([hidden_vectors,tags_input]) 
  conv_0=Conv1D(filters=filters, kernel_size=kernel_size, padding='same', activation='relu')(combined) 
  maxpool_1=GlobalMaxPooling1D()(conv_0)
  out=Dense(32, activation='relu')(maxpool_1)

  output = Dense(units=1,kernel_regularizer=l2(0.01))(out) 
  output=Activation(conv_activation)(output)
  model = Model(inputs=all_input, outputs=output)#tags_input,acoustic_input
  losses=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy()
  model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss=losses, metrics=['accuracy'])
  print(model.summary())#
  return model
```

Here is the model summary:
[image]

This 387 is the maximum number of utterances. How can we pass mask in lstm layer so that it knows that out of 387 how many are padded utterances and ignore it and same is transferred in subsequent layers?

Answer (score 1):

According to the Keras [guidelines](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/masking_and_padding), you can do this:

```
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(None,), dtype="int32")
x = layers.Embedding(input_dim=5000, output_dim=16, mask_zero=True)(inputs)
outputs = layers.LSTM(32)(x)
model = keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
```

And this internally passes the masking information to the following layer. You don't need to specify it manually.